# Mysql Query issues using LIKE and apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have an interesting issue that I have never come across and can't seem to find much information about correcting the issue. I have massive database that has an enormous amount of data in it (10 years worth), and attempting to search through it.

Now the search stuff works fine, but recently someone brought it to my attention about a 'bug' if you will. I've tried to trouble shoot it to get the expected results, but to no avail.

This is my issue:

When someone uses an apostrophe in the search, it's not that the search faults out, But it returns no results. So for example when searching `Pete's` the query executes but returns nothing. Yes, I make sure the query has the mysql_real_escape_string() so that `Pete's` becomes `Pete\'s`.

Even when I try to query it using phpmysql's search feature, I get strange results. The query is intended to be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `smd_article` WHERE  `copy` LIKE  '%Pete\'s%'
```

But when I use the search feature in phpmyadmin, it gives me:

```
SELECT * FROM  `smd_article` WHERE  `copy` LIKE  '%Pete''s%'
```

And when I actually type out the query in the sql tab, it still returns no results. But there are some 17K records that get returned when I just use Pete and some 3k records when I do just Petes.

So I am curious as to what I am doing wrong, or missing to make it so that it can allow for the apostrophe in a query using the LIKE statement. Thoughts?

Comment: off topic, but it's worth knowing that wildcard queries like this are the slowest possible way to query a database. I may be okay for a small table, but if you've got even a moderately big table, it can really slow things down. Be warned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try by `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($find) . "%'
```

or

```
 LIKE  '%Pete%27s%'
```

or if you are using pdo you can do like

```
$search ='Pete\'s'
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM  `smd_article` WHERE  `copy` LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: so what is stored in database ? isnt it `Pete\'s` or Pete's? if its `Pete's` it mean you are allowing `'` in other word your code is vunerable to sql injection

Comment: I never even thought to just take a look at the raw data. And now that I have, I see the issue. The title has: Pete&#39;s and in the content it has Pete&rsquo;s - eh. I hate how this site's editors just copy and paste content

Comment: OP mentioned that he is using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Also, having `Pete's` stored in database does not imply SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not because of the `'` single quote. You escaped it correctly. (as the search function in phpmyadmin):

> String: Pete's
>
> MySQL: 'Pete''s'

So the following query will work. (I've tested it)

```
SELECT *
FROM `smd_article`
WHERE copy
LIKE '%Pete''s%'
```

You can also have a look at the `IN` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM `smd_article`
WHERE copy
IN (
 'Pete', 'Pete''s'
)
```

Comment: @MrTechie I have tested the query with example data and it worked. The escaping of the quote is not the problem. Must be a different problem