# How to use apostrophe in LIKE operator on a WHERE clause? Example - WHERE WORD like '%That's why%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server how do I use an apostrophe in the LIKE operator on a WHERE clause?

Example: `WHERE WORD like '%That's why%'`

I need to fetch the data that matches to word "That's why" in the WORD column.

Dummy data on WORD Column:

1. So **that's why** we turned back
2. and **that's why** it didn't work

When I use `'%That\'s why%'`, I get

> Incorrect syntax near 's'

When I use `'%That''s why%'`, I get the following error

> Incorrect syntax near 's why%'

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651360/mysql-query-issues-using-like-and-apostrophe

Comment: replace the opening and closing bracket with a double-quote (`"`) or use escaping like `'%That\'s why%'`

Comment: @tcadidot0 when I use `'%That\'s why%'` , i get ,

Incorrect syntax near 's'

Comment: So, I assume this database of yours is actually not MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I'm on MSSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE WORD like '%That''s why%'`

Example (SQL Server):

[image]

Comment: Non-recommended technique. Use standard quoting with backslash char.

Comment: Why it is non-recommended technique? I thought that the only way to escape an apostrophe in MSSQL. Can you please explain @Akina

Comment: In MySQL (this is 1st tag). Test `SELECT '%That''s why%', '%That' 's why%';` :)

Comment: @SaiAbhiramInapala When I use '%That''s why%' , I get the following error 
** - Incorrect syntax near 's why%' **

Comment: @pandajemstome it's not double quote but 2 single quotes. Are you using mysql or mssql

Comment: @SaiAbhiramInapala I have used single quote and working on MSSQL

Comment: If your problem is resolved please mark the answer as answered by clicking the tick sign on left side of the answer

Comment: How to use the same in In operator. It works in Like but not on IN